# fails to overwrite property/class with new empty value before saving to viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, user-controls, viewstate

i'm building a control that inherits from `CompositeControl` and creates/maintains a number of dynamically generated child controls. i'm trying to save a class to viewstate before the control tears down the control hierarchy and rebuilds it with a new set of dynamically generated controls. other than persisting this class (as xmlserialized) in viewstate on save, i have no viewstate customization and i am not overriding `SaveViewState`, `SaveControlState`, etc.

what's happening in the code below: i have a `MySuperClass` property on the control that handles my info from load to render. to persist the info through paging events i added a `MySuperClassStore` to hold onto it. currently, the only data being changed by users is within `SubClassControl`'s `SubClass.SubClassResponse` (not shown). these changes are being correctly handed back to the `SuperClass` at the `SuperClassControl` level (using `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

the problem: seems to occur on postback (`OnControlSave` & `OnControlPageChange`) when you have an existing `SuperClass` already in viewstate. i'm picking up the existing `SuperClass`, updating it with new responses, and saving it back to viewstate. but if the `SubClassResponse` coming from user input is set to empty (by erasing text from or un-selecting the items in the child controls of the `SubClassControl`), the empty response class (not `null`; actually initialized as `ValueType.Empty`) does not update the corresponding entry in the `MySuperClassStore` before saving back to the viewstate. i've even tried to clear the value in `SubClassCollection.UpdateResponse()` before setting it, but no luck. i thought i might have a problem with my `IEquatable<>` but it seems fine. new response values and (non-empty) updated response values are both correctly updated and saved to the viewstate on each save/page change.

*BUT (and here's where i'm losing it)*, when i pop some breakpoints in and step through the code (vs2010), it correctly overwrites the removed entry with the empty (but initialized!) response class and saves back to viewstate (in `MySuperClassStore`). perfect. every single time. until i quit the debugger, and then it stops working.

#### stripped down version of my classes:

```
public class SuperClass {
    public Guid SuperClassId { get; set; }
    public SubClassCollection ThisCollection { get; set; }
    public static SuperClass Deserialize(string s) { /* deserialize xml */ }
}
public class SubClassCollection : KeyedCollection<Guid, SubClass> {
    public void UpdateResponse(Guid id, SubClassResponse scr) {
        this[id].Response = scr;
        //this[id].Response = (!scr.IsEmpty) ? scr : new SubClassResponse();
        //** seriously?!? that didn't fix it?
    }
}
public class SubClass {
    public Guid SubClassId { get; set; }
    public int SomeIntProp { get; set; }
    private SubClassResponse _response;
    public SubClassResponse Response {
        get { return (_response != null) ? this._response : new SubClassResponse(); }
        set { if (!_response.Equals(value)) { _response = value; OnPropertyChanged("Response"); } }
    }
}
public class SubClassResponse : IEquatable<SubClassResponse> {
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public ValueType ThisValueType { get; set; }
    public bool IsEmpty {
        switch (this.ThisValueType) {
            case ValueType.Empty: return true; break;
            case ValueType.StringValue: return String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Value); break;
            case ValueType.ListItemCollection: /* check for null, then .Count > 0 */ break;
            default: return true; break;
        }
    }
    public enum ValueType { Empty, StringValue, ListItemCollection, Etc }
}
```

#### and my top-level control has this going on:

```
public class SuperClassControl : CompositeControl, INamingContainer {
    // OnInit: load MySuperClass from db
    // OnPreRender: get MySuperClassStore from viewstate and output as debug info
    protected SuperClass MySuperClass { get; set; }
    protected SuperClass MySuperClassStore {
        get {
            return (ViewState["SuperClassStore"] == null) ? new SuperClass() : SuperClass.Deserialize((string)ViewState["SuperClassStore"]);
        }
        set { ViewState["SuperClassStore"] = value.ToSerialized(); }
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls() {
        // generate control hierarchy
        SuperClass mysuperclass = this.MySuperClass;
        foreach (SubClass mysubclass in mysuperclass.ThisCollection) {
            this.Controls.Add(new SubClassControl(mysubclass));
        }
        // add top-level control linkbuttons, hook up events, etc...
    }
    protected void OnControlSave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SuperClass mysuperclass = this.MySuperClass;
        SuperClass mystorageclass = this.MySuperClassStore;
        // loop through control hierarchy, make sure we've got any response changes
        // copy the changes to mystorageclass for persistence

        // ***** problem is occurring here?? *****
        foreach (Guid g in mysuperclass.ThisCollection.HasChanges) {
            mystorageclass.ThisCollection.UpdateResponse(g, mysuperclass.ThisCollection[g].Response);
        }

        // if the current page only displayed i=5 to 8, will only update i=5 to 8
        this.MySuperClassStore = mystorageclass;
    }
    protected void OnControlPageChange(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        OnControlSave(sender, e);
        // set next or previous page index then reset control hierarchy
    }
}
```

any thoughts? i've been messing with this for several days now, and i'm running out of ideas. thanks in advance!

will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, i solved this problem by inverting the update process:

```
mystorageclass.ThisCollection.UpdateResponse(g, mysuperclass.ThisCollection[g].Response);
this.MySuperClassStore = mystorageclass;
```

to:

```
mysuperclass.ThisCollection.UpdateResponse(g, mystorageclass.ThisCollection[g].Response);
this.MySuperClassStore = mysuperclass;
```

where the loop gets all `SubClass` NOT existing on the current page.

i works, so "yay?" - but i'm still at a loss for why this actually works better than the original piece of code, so if anyone has some insight into this, i'll happily give you points for the answer!